# Translate Pojo to JSON

Tags: java, jackson, xhtml, thymeleaf, pojo

I do the documentation. In pdf, my object should look like json. 
I create a collection of objects:

```
Arrays.asList(new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9)),
              new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(10, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.8)),
              new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(40, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7))
)
```

CoefficientPerQuantityParameter looks like this

```
public class CoefficientPerQuantityParameter {
    private Integer hour;
    private BigDecimal cost;
}
```

And I accept it in the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>My document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
             <p th:text="${coefficientPerQuantityParameter}"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to see the result in the form of JSON. But I see something completely different:

```
[CoefficientPerQuantityParameter
(hour=2, cost=0.9),
CoefficientPerQuantityParameter
(hour=10, cost=0.8),
CoefficientPerQuantityParameter
(hour=40, cost=0.7)]
```

How to get it?

```
{"2": 0.9,  "10": 0.8,   "40": 0.7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most classical way to serialise above list of `POJO` instances is to serialise it as array.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<CoefficientPerQuantityParameter> coefficients = Arrays.asList(new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9)),
                new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(10, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.8)),
                new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(40, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7)));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(coefficients));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[ {
  "hour" : 2,
  "cost" : 0.9
}, {
  "hour" : 10,
  "cost" : 0.8
}, {
  "hour" : 40,
  "cost" : 0.7
} ]
```

If you want to have a structure where `hour` is a key and `cost` is a value I suggest to convert given array to `Map` manually and serialise result.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<CoefficientPerQuantityParameter> coefficients = Arrays.asList(new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9)),
                new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(10, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.8)),
                new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(40, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7)));

        Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map = coefficients.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(CoefficientPerQuantityParameter::getHour, CoefficientPerQuantityParameter::getCost));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "2" : 0.9,
  "40" : 0.7,
  "10" : 0.8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using `th:inline="javascript"`.  You'll still have to convert your data to a `Map<String, Double>` to get the output layout you want.  For example:

Controller

```
List<CoefficientPerQuantityParameter> list = Arrays.asList(
        new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.9)),
        new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(10, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.8)),
        new CoefficientPerQuantityParameter(40, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7))
);

Map<String, BigDecimal> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        o -> "" + o.getHour(),
        CoefficientPerQuantityParameter::getCost)
);
```

Template

```
<span th:inline="javascript">[[${map}]]</span>
```

Output

```
<span>{"2":0.9,"40":0.7,"10":0.8}</span>
```